# How do I determine the indentlevel to customize showbreak?

Tags: vimrc, indentation, wrapping

I want wrapped lines to look like this:

```
some really long line that |
... reached the end of the |
... window.                |
const indented = () => {   |
  // a really, really,     |
  ... really long comment  |
}                          |
```

I want to do `let &showbreak = repeat(" ", /* something here */) . "... "` in my `vimrc`, but I'm not sure how to get the indent level.  I know of `indent({lnum})` but I'm not sure how to *refer to* the line being wrapped.

---

EDIT

currently, I get this:

```
some really long line that |
... reached the end of the |
... window.                |
const indented = () => {   |
  // a really, really,     |
...really long comment     |
      // extra tabs on this|
...   long comment         |
}                          |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `breakindent` along with `showbreak=…`. You can control the indent with `breakindentopt`.

Comment: Hey hey, so I have a `showbreak` set but I want the text of the showbreak to be applied _after_ applying the `shift{n}` indent - or to at least simulate this by adding the proper amount of whitespace before each `showbreak` - I just don't know how to refer to "the amount of leading whitespace on the line being wrapped"

Comment: @AaronParisi please see `:help breakindent`, the option I mentioned in my answer. It gives me something like what you want.

Comment: I see the following in the description of column{n}: "Note: an additional indent may be added for the 'showbreak' setting" - is that what you mean?

Comment: To be clear - I know how to indent the file content that is being wrapped.  I just need to indent the value of showbreak as well

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean - set breakindent showbreak=... _on the same line_